# How to display an iframe on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I just want to know how can I display an `iframe` on button click

Here is my code:

```js
function postYourAdd () {
    var iframe = $("#forPostyouradd");
    iframe.attr("src", iframe.data("src")); 
}
```

```html
<button id="postYourAdd" onclick="postYourAdd()">Button</button>
<iframe id="forPostyouradd" data-src="http://www.w3schools.com" src="about:blank" width="200" height="200" style="background:#ffffff"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At least in the Snippet you provided, you forgot to add a reference to JQuery. See it working now:

```js
function postYourAdd () {
    var iframe = $("#forPostyouradd");
    iframe.attr("src", iframe.data("src")); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="postYourAdd" onclick="postYourAdd()">OPEN</button>
<iframe id="forPostyouradd" data-src="http://www.w3schools.com" src="about:blank" width="500" height="200" style="background:#ffffff"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<body>
<p>This is IFrame</p>
    <button onclick="displayIframe()">Click me</button>
  <div id="iframeDisplay"></div>  

<script>
    function displayIframe() {
        document.getElementById("iframeDisplay").innerHTML = "<iframe src=\"../HtmlPage1.html\" height=\"200\" width=\"300\" ></iframe>";

    }
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function postYourAdd () {
    var iframe = $("#forPostyouradd");
    iframe.attr("src", iframe.data("https://www.google.com/")); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="postYourAdd" onclick="postYourAdd()">OPEN</button>
<iframe id="forPostyouradd" data-src="http://www.w3schools.com" src="about:blank" width="500" height="200" style="background:#ffffff"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

<button id="postYourAdd" onclick="light()">OPEN</button>
<iframe id="forPostyouradd" src="" title="W3Schools Free Online Web Tutorials">
</iframe>

<script>
function light() {
    var iframe = $("#forPostyouradd");
    debugger;
    iframe.attr("src", "https://www.w3schools.com/java/default.asp"); 
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```